# Complicated situation regarding monthly salary DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, tourist-visas

**Context**:

- Wife is an Indian citizen, currently working as a salaried employee in India.
- She has her USA tourist visa appointment next month.
- She is currently working at a 30% pay cut (since 8 months) because of some financial / funding complications at her company. The company has promised to restore her salary as soon as the funding goes through and will also back-pay the amount of total pay-cut.

In the DS-160 form, there is a section to write the **monthly salary in local currency**. My question is, in the case of my wife, what should be written in this section?

- Current salary (after the 30% pay cut) that she gets in her bank (after tax deductions).
- Her original monthly salary before the 30% pay cut after tax deductions.
- Average of all the monthly salaries that she has got since the last year.
- The amount that she paid total taxes on in her last Income tax return?

I understand that this entire situation is needlessly complicated, and the visa officers are expecting one simple number here. I just want to understand what would be the most straightforward way here?

Which document would be a better proof in this case?

1. Bank statements with salary credits.
2. Salary slips from the company.
3. Income tax return filed for the last  year.

Note: I know there are a few duplicate questions regarding monthly salary, but none of them explained my situation, so asking this. If possible, please also provide a link to any official US document or website which clarifies this. I tried, but didn't find any official information on what to write here.

Comment: I think what she currently gets is the most reasonable option: it would match salary slips and bank statements. Anything else would just lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: I doubt there’s any official guidance specifically covering this situation. I don’t see that it’s particularly complicated, although I can see why you would like to be able to show a higher income level. If the application asks about monthly salary, you can only state what she is currently receiving (and has been receiving for quite a long time). The fact that it’s only 30% of her previous level and there’s a promise to reinstate it at some unspecified date in the future (which may never happen) is irrelevant IMHO.

Comment: @Traveller, post as an answer not as a comment, especially as most of what you say has already been posted in an earlier comment